# How to create a DateTime object from DateTime and TimeSpan type?

Tags: c#, api, datetime, google-calendar-api

I'm using `Google Calendar API`, now I've created a class called GEvent, this is the structure:

```
public class GEvent
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

where `StartDate` is the day when the event start, and `StartTime` is the hour of that day.

I fill this field like this:

```
Calendar.GEvent eventD = new Calendar.GEvent();

eventD.StartDate = StartDate.SelectedDate.Value;
eventD.StartTime = TimeStart.SelectedTime.Value;
```

where `StartDate` is a `DatePicker` and `TimeStart` is a `TimePicker` (custom control for get only the hour).

When I create the event for `Google Calendar API` I declare it like so:

```
 Event myEvent = new Event
{
    Start = new EventDateTime()
    {
            DateTime = new DateTime(eventD.StartDate, eventD.StartTime),
            TimeZone = "Europe/Rome"
    }
    ... 
};
```

How you can see I can't create a `DateTime` object by the union of two object. How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DateTime.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add a `TimeSpan` to an existing `DateTime`.

```
Event myEvent = new Event
{
    Start = new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime = eventD.StartDate.Add(eventD.StartTime)),
        TimeZone = "Europe/Rome"
    }
}
```

Or as Jon stated, you can just add the two values:

```
...
DateTime = eventD.StartDate + eventD.StartTime,
...
```

*(This is possible because [DateTime overrides the + operator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,1203). It accepts a DateTime and TimeSpan value, adds the two, and returns a new DateTime.)*

Comment: Or just use the operator: `eventD.StartDate + eventD.StartTime`.